# Accessing non-subscriptable properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, attributes, members

Scripting the Blender, I successfully did `bpy.ops.render.render(some_args)` but `bpy.ops.render['render']` fails with BPyOpsSubMod object is not subscriptable. This puzzles me since I expected that, likewise in Javascript, any Python object is a dictionary and I can access object methods either by `obj.member` or `obj['member']`. How do I work around the non-subscriptable properties when I want to reference them by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that every object *is* a dictionary. But most objects *have* a dictionary, accessible through the name [`.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).

You can use either

```
bpy.ops.render.__dict__['render']
```

or

```
getattr(bpy.ops.render, 'render')
```

Comment: *Every object has a dictionary* is **False**: `[].__dict__`? Accessing `__dict__` may work in OP's case if they have a function

Comment: `bpy.ops.render.__dict__` fails `with AttributeError __dict__`

Comment: but `getattr` seems to give what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is inside a non-subscriptable object that does not have a **dict** you can do this:

```
import csv # use csv dialect as example object
a = csv.get_dialect('excel')
field_names = [v for v in dir(a) if not v.startswith('__')]
fields = [(getattr(a, v),v) for v in field_names]

print(fields)
```